# Android Media Player - DRM - Widevine

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, drm, widevine

I have this stream with Widevine DRM protection:
https://amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/622b189f-ec39-43f2-93a2-201ac4e31ce1/BigBuckBunny.ism/manifest

I have to reproduce it using **Android MediaPlayer**, but I didn't find any example of how to actually implement it. I already play a video without Widevine protection, so I wanted to know what else I need to play a video but with Widevine DRM protection.

**I'm using Android Studio and running on Android Pie the app.**

Here is the **activity_main.xml** code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="390dp"
        android:layout_height="530dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.521"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_raw"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="Play With Widevine Protection" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the **MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.mediaplayerbasic;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private VideoView videoView;
    private int position = 0;
    private MediaController mediaController;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        this.button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_raw);

        if (this.mediaController == null) {
            this.mediaController = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);
            this.mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
            this.videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        }

        this.videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

                videoView.seekTo(position);
                if (position == 0) {
                    videoView.start();
                }
                mediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
                        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        this.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String resName = VideoViewUtils.URL_VIDEO_SAMPLE;
                VideoViewUtils.playURLVideo(MainActivity.this, videoView, resName);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        savedInstanceState.putInt("CurrentPosition", videoView.getCurrentPosition());
        videoView.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        position = savedInstanceState.getInt("CurrentPosition");
        videoView.seekTo(position);
    }
}
```

And here is the **VideoViewUtils.java**:

```
package com.example.mediaplayerbasic;


import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoViewUtils {

    public static final String RAW_VIDEO_SAMPLE = "assembly_line";
    public static final String LOCAL_VIDEO_SAMPLE = "/res/raw/assembly_line.mp4";
    public static final String URL_VIDEO_SAMPLE = "https://amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/622b189f-ec39-43f2-93a2-201ac4e31ce1/BigBuckBunny.ism/manifest";


    public static final String LOG_TAG = "AndroidVideoView";


    public static void playRawVideo(Context context, VideoView videoView, String resName) {
        try {
            int id = VideoViewUtils.getRawResIdByName(context, resName);

            Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + id);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Video URI: " + uri);

            videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
            videoView.requestFocus();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error Play Raw Video: " + e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error Play Raw Video: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void playLocalVideo(Context context, VideoView videoView, String localPath) {
        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error Play Local Video: " + e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error Play Local Video: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void playURLVideo(Context context, VideoView videoView, String videoURL) {
        try {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Video URL: " + videoURL);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoURL);

            videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
            videoView.requestFocus();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error Play URL Video: " + e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error Play URL Video: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static int getRawResIdByName(Context context, String resName) {
        String pkgName = context.getPackageName();
        int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "raw", pkgName);

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Res Name: " + resName + "==> Res ID = " + resID);
        return resID;
    }
}
```

**Using VideView and MediaPlayer, what else I have to code for adding the Widevine DRM protection support to my app?
Thanks!**

Comment: The MediaPlayer supports Widevine DRM from API 26+ https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer#drm. For backwards compatibility I suggest using https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer which is a first party library by Google and widely used in the media industry.

Comment: Yes, i already read that documentation, but i dont understand how is the way to add the widevine drm functionality to the app, and i wanted to use MediaPlayer, not ExoPlayer

Comment: Hi @Matias! Were you able to find a solution to this question? I am also struggling with this.